# MIME-Type for Excel XML (ASP.NET 3.5)

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, mime-types

I use CarlosAG-Dll which creates a XML-Excel-file for me (inside a MemoryStream).

```
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "myfile.xml");
memory.WriteTo(Response.OutputStream);
```

My Problem here is, that I get at client side a myfile.xls (IE) or a myfile.xml.xls (FF) and therefore get an annoying security warning from excel.

I tried it as well with application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet (xlsx) but then it won't even open.

So I need to either cut the .xml and send it as vnd.ms-excel (how?) or take another MIME-type (but which one?).

---

edit: I found a bug description [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsofficedeveloper/archive/2008/03/11/excel-2007-extension-warning.aspx)

I wonder if this is still open and why?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use like this

```
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";

Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=myfile.xls");
```

For Excel 2007 and above the MIME type differs

```
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";

Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=myfile.xlsx");
```

See list of MIME types

[Office 2007 File Format MIME Types](https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsofficedeveloper/archive/2008/05/08/office-2007-open-xml-mime-types.aspx)

**EDIT:**

> If the content is not a native Excel file format, but is instead a
> text based format (such as CSV, TXT, XML), then the web site can add
> the following HTTP header to their GET response to tell IE to use an
> alternate name, and in the name you can set the extension to the right
> content type:
>
> ```
> Response.AddHeader "Content-Disposition", "Attachment;Filename=myfile.csv"
> ```

For more details see **[this link](https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsofficedeveloper/archive/2008/03/11/excel-2007-extension-warning.aspx)**

Comment: I do know those MIME-types but none of them fit my requirements (excel-xml-file with extension .xml).

Comment: Please see the edited part of the answer, which is found as a solution to your problem.

Comment: I added the "attachment" to my tests, now my client wants to open it with my standard xml-application (can be none elsewhere) after clicking open it opens in Excel (but only in IE). If I do so in FF it still transforms to .xml.xls

Comment: @UNeverNo See the last part of the link: "If the file was not in the right MIME type, the user may see a second prompt, and therefore has to press No again to cancel the second open attempt.  This issue only occurs when using IE for your web browser.  This issue is still being investigated, but a fix is not likely until Office 14 given the nature of the complexity of the code, and the fact that Excel does not want to lower the security measure to workaround IE open behaviors without a full understanding of the consequences for other browser users. "   :)

Comment: Thanks for your help, I think I'm going to live with the warning message for now...

Answer (score 1):

If your document is an Excel Xml 2003 document, you should use the text/xml content type.

```
Response.ContentType = "text/xml";
```

Do not specifiy content-disposition.

This technichs works great with Handler, not with WebForm.

Answer (score 0):

The security warning is NOT about the MIME type - it is a client-side security setting you can't disable from the server side !

Another point - change `Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "myfile.xml");` to:

```
Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=myfile.xlsx");
```

OR

```
Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "inline; filename=myfile.xlsx");
```

For reference see http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2183.txt

EDIT - as per comment:

IF the format is not XLSX (Excel 2007 and up) then use `myfile.xls` in the above code.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the generated file format is not Excel 2007 but an XML format introduced with Excel 2003. So the file extension .xlsx isn't correct and Excel probably won't even open it with that file extension.

Comment: @Codo thanks - IIRC that format you refer to was introduced with Excel 2000 - edited the answer accordingly...

Comment: I also tried .xls as extension but then i get the same error (that I try to open .xls but this extension differs from content [which is xml]) @Codo: Yep, that's what I wrote in my initial post (at least I tried ;-))