# Generated Excel file is downloaded as XML instead

Tags: php, xml, excel

I'm generating and using the following sample XML to generate and download an XLSX file.

```
<!--?xml version="1.0"?-->
<!--?mso-application progid="Excel.Sheet"?-->
<ss:workbook xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet">
    <ss:worksheet ss:name="Title">
        <ss:table>
            <ss:column>
                <ss:row>
                    <ss:cell><ss:data ss:type="String">Something</ss:data></ss:cell>
                    <ss:cell><ss:data ss:type="String">Something</ss:data></ss:cell>
                </ss:row>
            </ss:column>
        </ss:table>
    </ss:worksheet>
</ss:workbook>
```

I then use the following code snippet to force the file to download.

```
<?php
header("Pragma: public");
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Type: application/download");
;
header("Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=something.xml ");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary ");
print $this->file;
?>
```

The file downloads correctly; however, the extension is XML. I can manually open it in Excel and it would show correctly. I've tried changing the `filename` in the `Content-Disposition` line to `something.xlsx`, but when I try to open the file by double-clicking on it, I get a warning that:

> Excel cannot open the file something.xlsx because the file format or
>   file extension is not valid. Verify that the file has not been
>   corrupted and that the file extension matches the format of the file.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? Is the XML not in the right format?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8166205/mime-type-for-excel-xml-asp-net-3-5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to set the Content-Type once, and you should set it to the correct value:

```
<?php
header("Pragma: public");
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=something.xlsx");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
echo $this->file;
```

Also best to leave off trailing `?>` so that no stray whitespace gets into the downloaded file.